# Como calcular variação percentual por grupos no R

Tags: r, dplyr

Olá, pessoal

Estou tentando calcular a variação percentual por período e município, de modo que o R não considere o valor de outro município. O código é o seguinte:

```
emprego_rais_corrigido = left_join(emprego_rais_empilhado, Corretor, by = "Período") %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Localidade, Período) %>%
  mutate(Valor_corrigido = Valor*Fator) %>% 
  mutate(Variação = Valor_corrigido/lag(Valor_corrigido)-1)*100
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basicamente, gostaria que ele começasse a calcular do início a variação percentual da "Localidade" "Alto Paraiso", ficando NA na linha 12, sem considerar da Localidade anterior.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 0):

Ao agrupar por localidade e período, está obtendo um número de grupos igual ao nº de localidades multiplicado pelo nº de períodos, cada um com uma linha. Para o que deseja, os dados devem estar ordenados por localidade e período e serem agrupados por localidade apenas.

Como postou seus dados como imagem, vou usar um exemplo genérico.

```
library(dplyr)

# dados de exemplo
set.seed(76)
dados <- data.frame(
  localidade = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3),
  periodo = rep(2010:2012, 3),
  valor = rgamma(9, 10))

dados %<>%
  arrange(localidade, periodo) %>% # desnecessário se os dados já estiverem ordenados
  group_by(localidade) %>%
  mutate(variacao = valor/lag(valor))

dados
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#> # Groups:   localidade [3]
#>   localidade periodo valor variacao
#>   <chr>        <int> <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 A             2010 10.5    NA
#> 2 A             2011  8.97    0.854
#> 3 A             2012 11.8     1.32
#> 4 B             2010 11.4    NA
#> 5 B             2011 10.5     0.923
#> 6 B             2012 13.6     1.29
#> 7 C             2010 13.1    NA
#> 8 C             2011 10.0     0.764
#> 9 C             2012  7.73    0.770
```

O equivalente com *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dados)

setorder(dados, localidade, periodo)

dados[, variacao := valor/shift(valor), localidade]
```